# Using Image Resizer AzureReader2 with MVC website "The image cannot be displayed because it contains errors"

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, image-resizing, imageresizer

I'm trying to use Image Resizer's AzureReader2 plugin to read images from blob storage. And it works fine when I try and retrieve the unedited image.

When I go to the following url it redirects to my local storage account where the image is stored

```
http://localhost:2000/azure/test/image.jpg
```

But when I navigate to the following I get "The image cannot be displayed because it contains errors"

```
http://localhost:2000/azure/test/image.jpg?width=400&height=400&mode=crop&borderWidth=10&borderColor=red
```

Here is what my web.config file looks like

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="resizer" type="ImageResizer.ResizerSection,ImageResizer" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />

    <httpModules>
      <add name="ImageResizingModule" type="ImageResizer.InterceptModule" />
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
...
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <appSettings>
 ...
  </appSettings>
<system.webServer>
   <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
        <!-- This is for IIS7/8 Integrated mode-->
    <add name="ImageResizingModule" type="ImageResizer.InterceptModule" />
  </modules> 

</system.webServer>
  <resizer>
    <plugins>
      <add name="MvcRoutingShim" />
        <add name="AzureReader2" connectionString="UseDevelopmentStorage=true" endpoint="http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/" />
    </plugins>
  </resizer>
</configuration>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You'll need to use the Developer Tools > Network Tab to inspect the actual response bytes, and upload those somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if the problem was to do with my Owin pipeline. The way I had the rest of my project set up it was being routed through Owin and was never able to reach the Image Resizer. I changed the set up of my project so that it wasn't routing through Owin.